# parse checkboxes from a pdf in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, docsplit

I need to parse checkboxes from a PDF. I'm using [docksplit gem](http://documentcloud.github.io/docsplit/) of ruby.The problem is that when a pdf is parsed only its text gets parsed and there is no sign of check-box existence.

Here is a screenshot of my PDF checkbox( box marked with cross(X) is checked).

[image]

Is there any way I can figure it out weather its checked or unchecked.May be through binary data?

Comment: You can try gem pdf-reader, it has more functions and apis. In the document, the author mentions that AcroForm or other objects can be get from api. It's not be stored in text format.

Comment: @Bigxiang I'm not sure weather it can parse those checkboxes but once I tried parsing simple text and it couldn't even parse simple texts  from my pdf properly.